# If I get banned from a competitive game, do I keep the match to watch it over again?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

If get banned from a competitive game, can I go into my watch and view the replay of that competitive game? Or is it just deleted?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the latest games you played in your history. Even if you didn't play at least one round or got kicked.

If you are VAC banned you can still view your latest games and still participate in every non-competitive game mode. The games are just deleted from your and your party members game records, the demos are not deleted.

Side note: Your party members will be penalized, too, by revoking the wins of these games and adjusting their rank and profile.